# Pass a reference to a base class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code where I try to specialize a function template for each instance of a class (that may have been derived):

```
class Base {
};

class Derived:public Base {
};

template<Base& b>
void myfunction() {
   //use b somehow
}

Derived myobject;

int main() {
  myfunction<myobject>(); //this does not work
}
```

The code results in error message:

```
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'b'
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g4Zq03vewEJXH1i1)

How do I pass a reference to a static instance of type `Base`, given the static `Derived` object `myobject`?

Comment: `void main()`??

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with this? Why are you doing this? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and reflect about how it applies to your question (asking about a solution to an unknown problem).

Comment: So your template is <class T> - and your argument to the function is T& b;  and then your call is myFunc(myobj)

That said, it looks like there's a fundamental mis-understanding of templates, so I think you should revisit your book on them

Comment: You generally don't specialize functions but use overloads. `void myfunction(Base&)` would accept anything publically derived from `Base` (unless there is a closer match).

Comment: From the language point of view question seems to be legit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While *it is* fine to declare a template non-type **parameter** as a reference according to [[temp.param]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - ...
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - ...

The **argument** must follow the restrictions in [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.
>   **For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to** (or for a pointer
>   type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - **a subobject**,
> - ...

Which explicitly forbids what you are trying to do. Since `b` is going to end up referring to a sub-object.

The only solution which will make this compile, is adding another overload:

```
template<Derived & d>
void myfunction()
{
   //use d somehow
}
```

So you'll need to extract the common code out somehow.

Or, if you have C++17 available:

```
template<auto& b, std::enable_if_t<
                    std::is_base_of_v<Base, std::decay_t<decltype(b)>>
                  , void*> = nullptr>
void myfunction()
{
   //use b somehow
}
```

I suggest you re-think your general approach, however.

Comment: Yep the type of `d` would need to be known at compile time either way so the most elegant solution is the one you've proposed or with adding additional type of the parameter like `template <class T, T& d>` to fulfil compiler demands...